# Sql Cross Tab (Query)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My Query is:

```
SELECT
    Department.Dept_Name, 
    Patient.Patient_Type,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalPatients
FROM Patient 
INNER JOIN Payment 
    ON Patient.RegNo = Payment.RegNo 
INNER JOIN Department 
    ON Payment.DeptID = Department.Dept_ID
WHERE        (CONVERT(varchar, Patient.RegDateTime, 112) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE()-30, 112))
GROUP BY  
    Department.Dept_Name,
    Patient.Patient_Type
```

Result of this query is:

```
Dept_Name               |  Patient_Type  | TotalPatients
ACCIDENT & EMERGENCY    |   Entitled     |      5
MCH                     |   Entitled     |      4
ACCIDENT & EMERGENCY    |   General      |     410
BURN CARE CENTER        |   General      |      5
G-MEDICINE (CH)         |   General      |     20
G-SURGERY (CH)          |   General      |     12
MCH                     |   General      |     39
ACCIDENT & EMERGENCY    |   Staff        |     4
G-MEDICINE (CH)         |   Staff        |     1
BURN CARE CENTER        |   Referred     |     1
```

Result wanted:

```
Dept_Name               |  Entitled | General   | Staff | Referred |
ACCIDENT & EMERGENCY    |   5       |  410      | 4     | 0        |
MCH                     |   4       |  39       | 0     | 0        | 
BURN CARE CENTER        |   0       |   5       | 0     | 1        |
G-MEDICINE (CH)         |   0       |   20      | 1     | 0        | 
G-SURGERY (CH)          |   0       |   12      | 0     | 0        |
```

Please Help me to get my desire result.
Departments and Types can be increased or decreased.

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570614/sql-cross-tab-query?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the below with your provided sample data and it returns accordingly. Basically for each column you want to conditionally pass in the TotalPatients tot he SUM aggregator based on the PatientType value.

```
select
   Dept_Name
  ,sum(case when Patient_Type = 'Entitled' then TotalPatients ELSE 0 end) Entitled 
  ,sum(case when Patient_Type = 'General'  then TotalPatients ELSE 0 end) General   
  ,sum(case when Patient_Type = 'Staff'    then TotalPatients ELSE 0 end) Staff 
  ,sum(case when Patient_Type = 'Referred' then TotalPatients ELSE 0 end) Referred 
from @t
group by Dept_Name
```

In the cases where you need dynamic columns...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
       FROM   tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o 
       WHERE  o.xtype IN ( 'U' ) 
              AND o.id = Object_id(N'tempdb..#t')) 
  DROP TABLE #t; 

CREATE TABLE #t 
  ( 
  dept_name     NVARCHAR(255), 
 patient_type  NVARCHAR(255), 
 totalpatients INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #t 
        (dept_name, 
         patient_type, 
         totalpatients) 
Insert Into #T (Dept_Name, Patient_Type  , TotalPatients) 
SELECT department.dept_name,  
   patient.patient_type,  
   Count(*) AS TotalPatients  
FROM   patient  
   INNER JOIN payment  
           ON patient.regno = payment.regno  
   INNER JOIN department  
           ON payment.deptid = department.dept_id  
WHERE  ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, patient.regdatetime, 112) =  
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, Getdate() - 30, 112) )  
GROUP  BY department.dept_name,  
      patient.patient_type 

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(max), 
    @query AS NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(patient_type) 
                  FROM   #t 
                  GROUP  BY dept_name, 
                            patient_type 
                  ORDER  BY 1 
                  FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, 
           '') 

SET @query = N'SELECT Dept_Name, ' + @cols + N' 
         from               
         #T x             
         pivot              
           (                     
            SUM(TotalPatients)                 
            for Patient_Type in (' 
            + @cols + N')             
            ) p ' 

EXEC Sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Patient_Type can be more than 4.

Comment: Would the 5th value result in an additional column? Are you looking for a way to auto pivot based on each Patient_Type ?

Comment: Yes. Because I cannot know all Patient_Type.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to use a pivot approach.  I can provide an example if you aren't able to follow @Tony Dong's answer.

Comment: I still not be able to get my desired result by using @Tony Gog's answer. If you have some example than please share it to me.

Comment: Thanks Michael Buller. Thanks a lot. It works as I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot to make it works, this support dynamic columns

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Patient_Type) 
                    from  YourResultTable
                    group by Dept_Name, Patient_Type
                    order by 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT Dept_Name, ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                YourResultTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(TotalPatients)
                for Patient_Type in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: My query contain 3 different tables to get result. So how can I use it.

Comment: put your script replace yourResultTable will works, or create a tableVariable

Comment: SELECT        Department.Dept_Name, Patient.Patient_Type,COUNT(*) AS TotalPatients
FROM            Patient INNER JOIN
                         Payment ON Patient.RegNo = Payment.RegNo INNER JOIN
                         Department ON Payment.DeptID = Department.Dept_ID
WHERE        (CONVERT(varchar, Patient.RegDateTime, 112) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE()-30, 112))
GROUP BY  Department.Dept_Name,Patient.Patient_Type

Comment: above is my query how can I manage it into your provided script.

Comment: Give a alias name for your query like select * from (Your script) AS tempTable, if you think that is complex and hard to read, may a table variable, and insert all your select result into this table variable http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx